# Codeigniter file uploader class - filename as date & time

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to amend codeigniters' file uploader class so the filename of every file is the date & time, regardless of the filetype uploaded.

My current upload function is:

```
        function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['max_width']  = '1624';
        $config['max_height']  = '1268';
        $config['file_name']  = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28);

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        }
        else
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

            $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: What do you do if two files of the same type are uploaded at the same date and time?

Comment: Good point. Codeigniter seems to add-1, -2 etc to filenames the same.
It's quite possible that could happen i suppose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
$config['file_name']  = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28);
```

to be the date and time:

```
$config['file_name'] = date("Y_m_d H:i:s");
```

See PHP's [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to learn how to format it.

Comment: Thanks - I did try this but it didn't seem to work - trying again, you have the date formatted slightly different.